# How to start a sh script every x seconds?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a server With Linux, and i need to start a sh script with many commands every 5 secondes.

With crontab, minimum is 1 minute.

How can i do that ??

Thanks !

Comment: [**Repeat a unix command every x seconds forever**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [`watch`](http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html)

example

```sh
watch -n 5 foo.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `sleep` in a loop in shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    sh foo.sh
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: This will be 5 seconds between each call, not a call every 5 seconds.